# Can I draw a primitive shape to UWP inkcanvas?

Tags: c#, uwp, inkcanvas

I am coding a sketching interface using UWP inkcanvas. Basically, I need to provide feedback to the user's drawings, like checking stroke correctness, shape beautifulness etc.. I am thinking about providing interactive feedback directly on the ink canvas, using arrows, auxiliary lines to highlight the difference between the input and a template. The best way I can think of is to add extra shapes to inkcanvas, just like using drawLine in JPanel. But I kind of figured out that strokes is the only acceptable format in UWP inkcanvas. I am wondering if there is still any way I can use to achieve this goal?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

InkCanvas is not suitable for drawing something programmatically I believe. The easy way is ... just overlay the canvas like following,

```
<Grid>
  <InkCanvas x:name="myInkCanvas" />
  <Canvas x:name="myOverlayCanvas" />
</Grid>
```

and draw your shapes to the myOverlayCanvas.

Comment: Good idea. Thanks!

Comment: Hi, I also search a way to combine InkCanvas (for allowing the hand drawing) and Canvas (for easily using basic shapes).
But what is the easiest implementation for allowing user to add shapes, then resize and move them?